How can I keep alive Azure Service Bus client and sender instances for more than 10 minutes in Python SDK?
I'm currently working on integration of Azure Service Bus queue and custom gateway service. Every time service receives an event, it should send message to the dedicated queue.
I've managed to configure the async approach with establishing ServiceBusClient and ServiceBusSender instances.
However, according to the official documentation of the Azure SDK for Python, there is a 10 minutes limit of idle between AMQP operations.
In my case, the gap between events can exceed 10 minutes, so currently connection indeed becomes detached. And when event finaly arrives, it's re-created from a "cold start".
There is a keep-alive parameter, but it only shows frequency of calls within the 10 minutes timeframe.
I don't want to spend time on re-creations whenever the delay between events is 10+ minutes.
How can I avoid this? What is the safest way of resetting the IDLE timeout?
I've tried to reach the AMQP connection object, which is used under the hood - but it's not always there. There is also some LINK_CREDIT value, which is updated only when any legitimate action happens. But legit actions are all about sending messages to the queue, which I don't want to do.
Dummy messages to the queue also don't attract me, because it wastes resources and the queue is going to be processed by some other service.
Ideal state - some PING or Health Check call, just to keep the connection alive and refresh the IDLE timeout.

you can set keep-alive to 30 with below code
data_body = b'Hello from data message!'   application_properties = {"body_type": "data"}   data_message = ServiceBusMessage(       body=data_body,       application_properties=application_properties,       time_to_live=TIME_TO_LIVE   )

@NaveenSharma, thanks for the comment! As I mentioned, I don't want to create dummy messages, even for a short period of time.

I'm also looking for a solution without dummy messages but it's looking unavoidable. Service Bus is such a third rate messaging service, I really wish we were using SQS.

A Keep-Alive mechanism in messaging systems ensures that connections remain active, preventing timeouts and disconnections due to inactivity.You can implement it like this:
KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL = 300
 time.sleep(KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL)
     keep_alive_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_service_bus_alive, args=(servicebus_client, KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL))


To ensure the connection stays alive, you need to “ping” the service bus more frequently than the 10-minute idle timeout. A safe interval is around 5 minutes (300 seconds) or even less.
Time to Live (TTL) is a message property that specifies how long a message should be retained in the queue or topic before it is considered expired and eligible for removal.You can use it like this:
TIME_TO_LIVE = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)

def send_data_message(sender):
    data_body = b'Hello from data message!'
    application_properties = {"body_type": "data"}
    data_message = ServiceBusMessage(
        body=data_body,
        application_properties=application_properties,
        time_to_live=TIME_TO_LIVE
    )
    sender.send_messages(data_message)


If not dummy messages during a time/short period of time, remove the dummy message code during the time trial to avoid sending them in that time.
Below Python code is how to use both the keep-alive mechanism and time-to-live properties with Azure Service Bus.
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


CONNECTION_STRING = "AzureServiceBusConnectionString"

queue_name = "QueueName"

KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL = 300 

def keep_service_bus_alive(servicebus_client, interval):
    while True:
        try:
          
            logging.info("Pinging Service Bus to keep connection alive...")
            with servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name) as sender:
                logging.info("Connection kept alive")
            time.sleep(interval)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error keeping Service Bus alive: {e}")

def main():
 
    servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
    queue_sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name)
    queue_receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name)

    import threading
    keep_alive_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_service_bus_alive, args=(servicebus_client, KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL))
    keep_alive_thread.daemon = True  
    keep_alive_thread.start()

    logging.info("Sending two messages with TTL of  seconds")
    with queue_sender:
        for i in range(2):
            message = ServiceBusMessage(
                f'Message {i+1}',  
                time_to_live=timedelta(seconds=30) 
            )
            queue_sender.send_messages(message)
            time.sleep(1)  

    logging.info("Receiving messages")
    received_count = 0
    with queue_receiver:
        messages = queue_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=2, max_wait_time=5)
        for msg in messages:
            logging.info(f"Received message: {msg}")
            queue_receiver.complete_message(msg)
            received_count += 1

    assert received_count == 2, f"Expected 2 messages, but got {received_count}"

    logging.info("Test completed successfully")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



Output:

For more details, refer to the git and this link for information on Keep-Alive.

I would add threading locks here as the servicebus sender is not threadsafe
